# Unity Particle System is rendering outside a masked viewport

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have a ScrollView with a working mask that block images, text etc when not in the viewport (visible area).

The problem I have is that ALL particles sytems are ALWAYS rendering and visible on screen, whether they are part of the viewport or not.

I would to know:
1) if masking is possible on Particle Systems
2) and if it is what have I overlooked or missed that makes the particles visible.

FYI I have tried layers, adding a specific mask to the object to the object with the particle system, adding a mask to the parent of the object with the particle system, and randomly altering renderer settings, and I'm ready to cry.

Comment: Are you using a `RectMask2D` as your mask?

Comment: I am using the default mask when you create a Scroll View...unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the particle systems themselves, but with the shader the particles use.

The way Unity's <strike>Mask</strike> *Stencil* system works is through the stencil buffer, which only works if your shader plays nice with it. If you want to try to modify your shader for this, [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html) is the relevant documentation. Otherwise, try changing to a different shader or using a different method to hide your particles, such as modifying Camera.rect, for which the documentation is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html).

By the way, if we're being a stickler for terminology here, "viewport" doesn't mean what you think it means (within the context of computer graphics).

Comment: Do you actually know if any of the default shaders work? I thought they would since images are masked and sprites...but the same shaders on particles DO NOT WORK. That's my issue... same shaders, different results.

Comment: Hold on, are you using something called the Mask Element? Because that's something completely different that I actually should have considered. The Mask Element only works on Canvas Elements (Text, Images, etc). It won't work on world-space objects like cubes and particle systems. Or am I making another assumption somewhere? How is this set up?

Comment: I am using the mask element... is that the wrong approach?

Comment: It depends, but it seems like it would be far easier to change the "viewport rect" property on the camera element to the desired rectangle, as well as more reliable. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html

Comment: I can't do that because changing the main camera viewport removes everything else from view as well!